# Error Can't resolve all parameters for setupRouter

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am getting error "Can't resolve all parameters for RouteParams while creating a basic app for routing"

Below is my app.module.ts file looks like

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';


import { App } from './app';
   import { routing } from './components/appRouting/app.routing';
   import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/loginComponent';
   import {SliderMenuComponent} from './components/sliderMenu/sliderMenuComponent';

      @NgModule({
       imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         FormsModule,
         routing,
         HttpModule
       ],
       declarations: [App,LoginComponent,SliderMenuComponent],
       providers: [],
       bootstrap: [App]
     })
     export class AppModule { }
```

My app.routing.ts looks like as below:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/loginComponent';
import {SliderMenuComponent} from '../sliderMenu/sliderMenuComponent';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'slider', component: SliderMenuComponent }
    ];
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

My app.ts looks like below:

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   template : `
   <h1 class="title">Component Router</h1>
   <nav>
     <a routerLink="/slider" routerLinkActive="active">Slider</a>
     <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class App {
}
```

Comment: Please post how `routing` is defined. There are no `RouteParams` anymore. Do you try to inject it somewhere? Inject instead `ActivatedRoute` and use `this.route.params.forEach(params =>
                                console.log(params['someParam']))`

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Updated my question, i am new to angular2 and first time implementing routing

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  problem is here that i am getting run time error "Can't resolve all parameter for setupRouter". Could you please tell if i missing anything here, i am just trying to achieve simple routing on click of links

Comment: Do you inject `RouteParams` anywhere?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am using "import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';". Do i need to use RouteParams?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `RouteParams`. This is why I asked if you do. The error message in your question **does** indicate that you use it though.

Answer (score 2):

updated the angular router to "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2" and it's working now